# Upgrade Postgresql from 9.6 to 11 with different data directory

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to upgrade PostgreSQL version from 9.6 to 11. I am following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47233300/1357214). The problem is I have changed my default location of PostgreSQL data directory from `/var/lib/postgresql/` to `/opt/postgresql/`. So when I am using `pg_lsclusters` it is returning following

[image]

When I am running the `sudo pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.6 main` its returning following error

```
Error: move_conffile: required configuration file /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf does not exist
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a **custom data_directory** as an optional parameter to the command `pg_upgradecluster`:

```
pg_upgradecluster [-v newversion] oldversion name [newdatadir]
```

So for your case, it should be:

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster -m upgrade 9.6 main /opt/postgresql/11/main
```

Note that you must **first** remove any existing cluster at the specified location (`/opt/postgresql/11/main`) and create an empty directory with the correct owner before running pg_upgradecluster:

```
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 11 main
sudo mkdir -p /opt/postgresql/11/main
sudo chown postgres:postgres /opt/postgresql/11/main
```

Comment: Does this work? as I have custom data directory for the 9.6 version also